# Entity Framework CTP5: How to connect MySql database using C#?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am trying to use Entity Framework CTP5, from a simple project.
for now i added the reference to EntityFramework.dll (CTP5)
and then write some code. But now i am unable to use it:

**How to connect MySql database using C# ?**

for now i created:

```
public class EF5_DATABASE : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Sistema.Clientes.Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

but the following code is not working:

```
EF5_DATABASE db = new EF5_DATABASE();
db.Database.Connection = ERP.MyConnection;   // MyConnection is a connected MySqlConnection
```

it throws this compiler error:

```
    Error  8   Property or indexer 'System.Data.Entity.Database.DbDatabase.Connection' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\temp\WpfApplicationTEST\MainWindow.xaml.cs   48  13  WpfApplicationTEST
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to assign the connection? Why not just let EF create it? It's possible to do this, but it's not the easy way, and I wouldn't want to do it without a really good reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have written an [article](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html) illustrating some aspects of EF CTP 5 Code First support in [dotConnect for MySQL](http://devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/).
Hope this article will be helpful.